# Largest product in a series (java)

Tags: java, algorithm, math, numbers, series

I'm trying to find the 3 adjacent numbers that produce the maximum product given a 9 digit number. For example for the number 198348756 my solution should return [8,7,5] since the product of this is 280 and is the maximum product possible.My code finds the max product but cannot return the array of digits that create the max product. Instead it returns the last array it checks in the for loop. I cannot understand why the array of digits that create the max product isn't stored in the variable result?

```
  public class Solution {
  ArrayList<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<>();


  /// digits to int array
  void tocharArray(String num) {
    char[] charArray = num.toCharArray();

    for (Character c : charArray) {
      digits.add(Character.getNumericValue(c));
    }
    //System.out.println(digits);
    //System.out.println(digits.size());
  }


  //gets product of array ex [1,2,3] ->6
  int arrayproduct(ArrayList<Integer> array) {
    int product = 1;
    for(int i=0;i < array.size(); i++) {
      product = product * array.get(i);
    }
    return product;
  }


  ArrayList<Integer> func() {
    ArrayList<Integer> three = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();


    // array of the first 3 digits of the number
    for(int index = 0; index < 3;index++) {
      three.add(digits.get(index));
    }

    //initially the max product is the first 3 digits 
    int maxproduct = arrayproduct(three); 
    System.out.println(three); //from test [1,9,8]
    System.out.println(maxproduct);// from test 72

    ArrayList<Integer> copy = three;

    for(int j = 3 ; j < digits.size();j++) {

      copy.remove(0);
      copy.add(digits.get(j));
      int next = arrayproduct(copy);
      System.out.println(copy);

      if(next > maxproduct) {
        maxproduct = next;
        result = copy;
      }
    }
    System.out.println(maxproduct); // returns 280 which is correct 
    System.out.println(result); // returns [7,5,6]

    return result;

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test1 = "198348756";

    Solution sol = new Solution();
    sol.tocharArray(test1); \\[1,9,8,3,4,8,7,5,6]
    sol.arrayproduct(sol.digits); \\returns [7,5,6] which is incorrect
    sol.func();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
ArrayList<Integer> copy = three;
```

Your code assumes that `copy` is, well, a copy, but in reality it is an *alias* to the same `three` list.

You can fix it by actually copying the list:

```
ArrayList<Integer> copy = new ArrayList<>(three);
```

Same goes for `result = copy` - it needs to be `result = new ArrayList<>(copy)`

**Note:** You can further simplify this code by changing `arrayproduct` to take the initial index and length. This way you would be able to avoid creating new lists as you go. Once the proper location is found, you would be able to make a copy of three-element subrange by calling `subList`.

Comment: You were correct but what is the difference between result = copy and result = new ArrayList<>(copy)? I cannot understand how these two statements are referring to different data?

Comment: @ken24ny, refer to the source code of ArrayList.java, `new ArrayList<>(copy)` will copy the under layer array and return an new arrayList depends on it.

Answer (score 2):

A easier approach

```
ArrayList<Integer> getMaxConsecutive(ArrayList<Integer> arr)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int start=-1;
    int max=INT_MIN;
    for(int i=0;i<(arr.size()-3);i++)
    {
         int sum = arr.get(i)+arr.get(i+1)+arr.get(i+2);
         if(sum>max){
             max=sum;
             start = i;
         }
    }

    result.add(arr.get(start));
    result.add(arr.get(start+1));
    result.add(arr.get(start+2));

    return result;
}
```

Comment: okay, for that you could just replace the + with a *

and it will work like a charm

Answer (score 1):

From the source code:

```
for (int j = 3; j < digits.size(); j++) {

    copy.remove(0);
    copy.add(digits.get(j));
    int next = arrayproduct(copy);
    System.out.println("-->" + next);
    System.out.println("-->" + copy);

    if (next > maxproduct) {
        maxproduct = next;
        result = copy;
        System.out.println("result-->" + result);
    }
}
```

The variable copy and result are object references like a pointer of C.
So, you need to copy(clone) all contents of copy's contents to the result object explicitly whenever the maxproduct value changes. There are several ways to accomplish about this method.

Using a clone method is one simple way to do;

```
result = copy;
```

to

```
result = (ArrayList<Integer>)copy.clone();
```

So, the func method is as follows:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
ArrayList<Integer> func() {
    ArrayList<Integer> three = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

    // array of the first 3 digits of the number
    for (int index = 0; index < 3; index++) {
        three.add(digits.get(index));
    }

    // initially the max product is the first 3 digits
    int maxproduct = arrayproduct(three);
    System.out.println(three); // from test [1,9,8]
    System.out.println(maxproduct);// from test 72

    ArrayList<Integer> copy = three;

    for (int j = 3; j < digits.size(); j++) {

        copy.remove(0);
        copy.add(digits.get(j));
        int next = arrayproduct(copy);
        System.out.println(copy);

        if (next > maxproduct) {
            maxproduct = next;
            result = (ArrayList<Integer>)copy.clone();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(maxproduct); // returns 280 which is correct
    System.out.println(result); // returns [7,5,6]

    return result;

}
```

Then the output message might be what you expected.

```
[1, 9, 8]
72
[9, 8, 3]
[8, 3, 4]
[3, 4, 8]
[4, 8, 7]
[8, 7, 5]
[7, 5, 6]
280
[8, 7, 5]
```

Have a good coding...